# python django why class method can be used like a variable?

Tags: python, django

I see this in the UserCreationForm:

```
def clean_username(self):
    # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
    # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
    username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
    try:
        User._default_manager.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return username
    raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])
```

This method can be used in this way:

```
def register_me(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        uname = form.clean_username
```

**See the last line above**. The method is without the ()... Why???

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties

Comment: yes, can be a property, but.. are you using the instance method?

Comment: what do you get when you print `uname`?

Comment: @rednaw I got just a character '>'.. why? I am new to python django.. so please bear with me for these silly questions..

Comment: @rednaw no. username is a5

Answer (score 2):

This is because python is not strongly typed (so you can assign any kind of object to any variable) and because functions are first class objects: you can assign them to variables like any normal object.

In your example after assigning *form.clean_username* to *uname* you can use the *uname* variable like this: *uname()* and it will do the same as *form.clean_username()* because you assigned to *uname* the "runnable" that was referenced by *form.clean_username*

Comment: in this case yes, you are only creating a reference to the method, that didn't run yet